# Get the column of function call in php

Tags: php, function-calls

I want to be able to get the column of a function call in PHP.

With `debug_backtrace()`, I can get the line of the function call, but I cannot get the column.

What I want to do is to be able to distinguish two function calls on the same line.

For instance:

```
function test() {
    //do something with the line/column of the called function.
}

test(); test(); //How to know whether it is the first or second test() which is called?
```

Comment: That doesn't seem possible, unless you pass some sort of argument to flag the calls.

Comment: And it is bad practice to put two statements into the same line.

Comment: @Christian Gärtner: It is only an example. And there are ways to have two function calls in one statement.

Comment: Yeah ok. If you using the return values of the function as parameters for another function would be a use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can only identify the function call passing an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but this would be a way to differentiate between function calls

```
function($column){
//do something with $column

}

test(1); test(2);
```

Edit:

I misread your question, by column you mean (I think) the columnnumber in the source file.

I doubt this is possible because not even syntax errors give back column information.

Further more, debugging tools like xdebug also do not support breaklines at a specific column number.

So it seems doubtful